# Vertex displacement doesn't affect anything -- Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, vertex-shader

I'm trying to implement a simulation of an ocean based on [this tutorial](https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/creating-a-vertex-displacement-shader?uv=2019.4#) but I can't get my shader to affect my plane. It stays completly flat whatever I do.

This is my shader :

```
Shader "Custom/Waves"
{
    Properties
    {
        _Color ("Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
        _MainTex ("Albedo (RGB)", 2D) = "white" {}
        _Glossiness ("Smoothness", Range(0,1)) = 0.5
        _Metallic ("Metallic", Range(0,1)) = 0.0
        _NormalMap ("Normal Map", 2D) = "bump" {}

        //Wave Properties
        _Direction("Direction", Vector) = (1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
        _Steepness("Steepness", Range(0.1,1.0)) = 0.5
        _Freq("Frequency", Range(1.0,10.0)) = 1.0
    }
    SubShader
    {
        Tags { "RenderType"="Opaque" }
        LOD 200

        CGPROGRAM
        // Physically based Standard lighting model, and enable shadows on all light types
        #pragma surface surf Standard fullforwardshadows

        // Use shader model 3.0 target, to get nicer looking lighting
        #pragma target 3.0

        sampler2D _MainTex;


        float _Steepness, _Freq;
        float4 _Direction;
        struct Input
        {
            float2 uv_MainTex;
        };

        half _Glossiness;
        half _Metallic;
        fixed4 _Color;

        // Add instancing support for this shader. You need to check 'Enable Instancing' on materials that use the shader.
        // See https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/GPUInstancing.html for more information about instancing.
        // #pragma instancing_options assumeuniformscaling
        UNITY_INSTANCING_BUFFER_START(Props)
            // put more per-instance properties here
        UNITY_INSTANCING_BUFFER_END(Props)

        void vert(inout appdata_full v){   
            float3 pos = v.vertex.xyz;
            float4 dir = normalize(_Direction);
            float defaultWavelength = 2 * UNITY_PI;
            float wL = defaultWavelength / _Freq;
            float phase = sqrt(9.8/wL);
            float disp = wL * (dot(dir, pos) - (phase * _Time.y));
            float peak = _Steepness/wL;
            pos.x += dir.x * (peak * cos(disp));
            pos.y = peak * sin(disp);
            pos.z += dir.y * (peak * cos(disp));
            v.vertex.xyz = pos;
        }

        void surf (Input IN, inout SurfaceOutputStandard o)
        {
            // Albedo comes from a texture tinted by color
            fixed4 c = tex2D (_MainTex, IN.uv_MainTex) * _Color;
            o.Albedo = c.rgb;
            // Metallic and smoothness come from slider variables
            o.Metallic = _Metallic;
            o.Smoothness = _Glossiness;
            o.Alpha = c.a;
        }
        ENDCG
    }
    FallBack "Diffuse"
}
```

[image: Unity Screenshot]

I thought that it might be the link between the plane, the material and the shader but it doesn't seem to help. I don't have any idea of what I did wrong. I tried with and without GPU instancing and it does not change anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to declare that you want to use a vertex function.

Add this before or after the other pragma

```
#pragma vertex vert
```

Comment: Thank you ! It works fine ! It was a pretty dumb question but i'm new with shader graphics.

Comment: It wasn't a dumb question, shaders are hard. Good luck on your game dev journey.